# React native firebase : Error: [messaging/unknown] The operation couldn’t be completed. No APNS token specified before fetching FCM Token

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to setup push notification on ios and android using Firebase/mesaging.

I have followed the setup part using the googleservice-info and so on...
I have activated push notification and both Background mode capabilities we need. I pushed the APN key on firebase for the ios.

This is my code :

`index.js`

```
import { getMessaging } from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';

const credentials = {...}

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(credentials).then((app) => {
        getMessaging(firebase).setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
            console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
        });
    })
}
```

Then in my `app.tsx`

```
  const getFcmToken = async () => {
    console.log("trying to get")
    try {
      const newFcmToken = await messaging().getToken() // HERE
      console.log('newFcmToken');
      console.log(newFcmToken);
   } ...
 }
```

```
  const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
  if (!messaging().isDeviceRegisteredForRemoteMessages) {
    await messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages();
  }

  const enabled =
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;


  if (enabled) {
    console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
    await getFcmToken();
  }
```

`package-lock.json`

```
        "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.4.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.4.0",
```

and then I get a

```
 ERROR  [Error: [messaging/unknown] The operation couldn’t be completed. No APNS token specified before fetching FCM Token]
```

I try to add this in the `info.plist`

````
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    
<key>GCMessagingSenderId</key>
    <string>...</string> 
    ```


At some point I remembered succeeding having a token, I have one on the firebase dashboard.
````

Answer (score -1):

Your situation is not clear as to which version of the library are you using, how are you using it etc. However you may try these alternatives that can fix the problem:

**Solution 1: Configure Background Modes in Xcode**

- Go to the project settings in Xcode.
- Navigate to the "Signing & Capabilities" tab.
- Ensure that "Background Modes" is enabled.
- Select "Background fetch" and "Remote notifications" under "Background modes."

**Solution 2: Update Podfile**

In your Podfile, set `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static` to configure the linking of Firebase libraries as static frameworks. This may help resolve dependency issues:

```rb
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
```

**Solution 3: Modify `firebase.json` Configuration**

Change the configuration in your `firebase.json` file as follows:

From:

```json
{
  "react-native": {
    "analytics_auto_collection_enabled": false,
    "messaging_auto_init_enabled": false,
    "messaging_ios_auto_register_for_remote_messages": false
  }
}
```

To:

```json
{
  "react-native": {
    "analytics_auto_collection_enabled": false,
    "messaging_auto_init_enabled": false,
    "messaging_ios_auto_register_for_remote_messages": true
  }
}
```

And remove the call `await messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages()` from your code.

**Solution 4: Update `Info.plist` File**

Add the following property to your `Info.plist` file:

```xml
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

**Solution 5: Handling APNs Tokens on Simulators**

For simulators running on Intel Macs, there is no real APNs token available because they do not support APNS or FCM. To address this, you can set a bogus token for testing purposes. This strategy has been confirmed as valid by collaboration with the Firebase iOS SDK team. On M1 Macs running the latest macOS and iOS in the simulator, APNs and FCM are supported.

To set a bogus APNs token for simulators on Intel Macs:

```
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

// Check if running on a simulator
const isSimulator = () => {
  return (
    Platform.OS === 'ios' &&
    Platform.constants?.isDevice === false // iOS simulator check
  );
};

const initializeFirebase = async () => {
  const credentials = { ... }; // Your Firebase credentials

  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    await firebase.initializeApp(credentials);

    // If running on a simulator on an Intel Mac, set a bogus APNs token
    if (isSimulator()) {
      await messaging().setAPNSToken('74657374696E67746F6B656E', 'unknown');
      console.log('Bogus APNs Token set for simulator on Intel Mac');
    }
  }
};

// Call the initializeFirebase function when your app starts
initializeFirebase();
```

These solutions should help you resolve the error and configure Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) properly for your React Native app on iOS. Be sure to carefully implement these changes, and if you encounter any further issues, check for any additional error messages or warnings in the console logs for more information.

Comment: I dont have a firebase.json,  I will add with my package-lock.json
FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled was already at true
I'm running on device

Comment: Please note that AI-generated content is banned on this site.

Comment: @miken32 I have gone through these two issues page and then summarised all workable solutions. [1](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/6893) [2](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/6829) Why do you think this is AI-generated?