# The operation couldn’t be completed. No APNS token specified before fetching FCM Token - IOS React Native

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to setup push notifications in React Native using Firebase/messaging. When I try to get FCM Token, it throws this error only for IOS.

Sometimes it starts working when I hit and try different solutions, but the next day it will send the same error again.

I have followed all the solutions from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77128677/react-native-firebase-error-messaging-unknown-the-operation-couldn-t-be-com).

Here is my code:

```
const getFCMToken = async () => {
  try {
    const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
    console.log(fcmToken);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

export const requestPermissionAndFCMToken = async () => {
  if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

    if (enabled) {
      getFCMToken();
    }
  } else {
    const authStatus = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.POST_NOTIFICATIONS,
    );
    if (authStatus === "granted") {
      getFCMToken();
    }
  }
};
```